# How do I use the functions within this Python script?

Tags: python

I have this Python script to control a PfSense router via FauxAPI. The problem is that when i call a function it gives an error. I think i'm calling the function wrong. Does anyone know how to call them?
Here is a link to the API i'm using: https://github.com/ndejong/pfsense_fauxapi
I have tried calling config_get(self, section=none) but that does not seem to work.

```
import os
import json
import base64
import urllib
import requests
import datetime
import hashlib


class PfsenseFauxapiException(Exception):
    pass


class PfsenseFauxapi:

    host = '172.16.1.1'
    proto = None
    debug = None
    version = None
    apikey = 'key'
    apisecret = 'secret'
    use_verified_https = None

    def __init__(self, host, apikey, apisecret, use_verified_https=False, debug=False):
        self.proto = 'https'
        self.base_url = 'fauxapi/v1'
        self.version = __version__
        self.host = host
        self.apikey = apikey
        self.apisecret = apisecret
        self.use_verified_https = use_verified_https
        self.debug = debug
        if self.use_verified_https is False:
            requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

    def config_get(self, section=None):
        config = self._api_request('GET', 'config_get')
        if section is None:
            return config['data']['config']
        elif section in config['data']['config']:
            return config['data']['config'][section]
        raise PfsenseFauxapiException('Unable to complete config_get request, section is unknown', section)

    def config_set(self, config, section=None):
        if section is None:
            config_new = config
        else:
            config_new = self.config_get(section=None)
            config_new[section] = config
        return self._api_request('POST', 'config_set', data=config_new)

    def config_patch(self, config):
        return self._api_request('POST', 'config_patch', data=config)

    def config_reload(self):
        return self._api_request('GET', 'config_reload')

    def config_backup(self):
        return self._api_request('GET', 'config_backup')

    def config_backup_list(self):
        return self._api_request('GET', 'config_backup_list')

    def config_restore(self, config_file):
        return self._api_request('GET', 'config_restore', params={'config_file': config_file})

    def send_event(self, command):
        return self._api_request('POST', 'send_event', data=[command])

    def system_reboot(self):
        return self._api_request('GET', 'system_reboot')

    def system_stats(self):
        return self._api_request('GET', 'system_stats')

    def interface_stats(self, interface):
        return self._api_request('GET', 'interface_stats', params={'interface': interface})

    def gateway_status(self):
        return self._api_request('GET', 'gateway_status')

    def rule_get(self, rule_number=None):
        return self._api_request('GET', 'rule_get', params={'rule_number': rule_number})

    def alias_update_urltables(self, table=None):
        if table is not None:
            return self._api_request('GET', 'alias_update_urltables', params={'table': table})
        return self._api_request('GET', 'alias_update_urltables')

    def function_call(self, data):
        return self._api_request('POST', 'function_call', data=data)

    def system_info(self):
        return self._api_request('GET', 'system_info')

    def _api_request(self, method, action, params=None, data=None):

        if params is None:
            params = {}

        if self.debug:
            params['__debug'] = 'true'

        url = '{proto}://{host}/{base_url}/?action={action}&{params}'.format(
            proto=self.proto, host=self.host, base_url=self.base_url, action=action, params=urllib.parse.urlencode(params))

        if method.upper() == 'GET':
            res = requests.get(
                url,
                headers={'fauxapi-auth': self._generate_auth()},
                verify=self.use_verified_https
            )
        elif method.upper() == 'POST':
            res = requests.post(
                url,
                headers={'fauxapi-auth': self._generate_auth()},
                verify=self.use_verified_https,
                data=json.dumps(data)
            )
        else:
            raise PfsenseFauxapiException('Request method not supported!', method)

        if res.status_code == 404:
            raise PfsenseFauxapiException('Unable to find FauxAPI on target host, is it installed?')
        elif res.status_code != 200:
            raise PfsenseFauxapiException('Unable to complete {}() request'.format(action), json.loads(res.text))

        return self._json_parse(res.text)

    def _generate_auth(self):
        # auth = apikey:timestamp:nonce:HASH(apisecret:timestamp:nonce)
        nonce = base64.b64encode(os.urandom(40)).decode('utf-8').replace('=', '').replace('/', '').replace('+', '')[0:8]
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%dZ%H%M%S')
        hash = hashlib.sha256('{}{}{}'.format(self.apisecret, timestamp, nonce).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        return '{}:{}:{}:{}'.format(self.apikey, timestamp, nonce, hash)

    def _json_parse(self, data):
        try:
            return json.loads(data)
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            pass
        raise PfsenseFauxapiException('Unable to parse response data!', data)
```

Comment: Share the code that creates an instance of `PfsenseFauxapi` and uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having tested the above script myself, I can conclude that yes you are calling the function wrong. The above script is rather a class that must be instantiated before any function inside can be used.

**For example you could first create an object with:**

```
pfsense = PfsenseFauxapi(host='<host>', apikey='<API key>', apisecret='<API secret>')
```

*replacing `<host>`, `<API key>` and `<API secret>` with the required values*

**Then call the function with:**

```
pfsense.config_get() # self is not passed
```

*where `config_get` can be replaced with any function*

**Also note**

- As soon as you call `pfsense = PfsenseFauxapi(...)`, all the code in
  the `__init__` function is also run as it is the constructor (which
  is used to *initialize* all the attributes of the class).
- When a function has a parameter which is `parameter=something`, that `something` is the default value when nothing is passed for that parameter. Hence why `use_verified_https`, `debug` and `section` do not need to be passed (unless you want to change them of course)

[Here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/python/object-oriented-programming/classes-and-objects-i/tutorial/#:%7E:text=A%20class%20is%20a%20code,the%20instance%20of%20the%20class.) is some more information on classes if you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object of the class in order to call the functions of the class. For example
`x = PfsenseFauxapi()` (the init method is called during contructing the object)
and then go by `x.'any function'`. Maybe name the variable not x for a good naming quality.